# sqlalchemy: concat strings with + sign

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I try to concatenate 3 parts together into an SQL expression with `sqlalchemy`:

```
func.date(cls.entry_date, '+' + cls.duration + ' year', '-1 day')
```

The SQL statement produced is:

```
date("My_Table"."Entry date",  '+' + "My_Table"."Durée" || ' year', '-1 day', '-1 day')
```

instead of

```
date("My_Table"."Entry date",  '+' || "My_Table"."Durée" || ' year', '-1 day', '-1 day')
```

The last sign `+` is correctly transformed to `||` (between "My_Table"."Durée" and ' year')

The first sign `+` is left as is in SQL statement (between '+' and "My_Table"."Durée")

I cannot figure out why.

I tried to change the string character`'+'` to some other character as I thought it could interfere with the concatenation `+` but it does not change anything.

**Edit**

I tried to use `func.concat('+', cls.duration, ' year')` but sqlite does not understand `concat`.

Of course I could use f-strings:

```
func.date(cls.entry_date, f"""'+ "{cls.duration.name}" year'""", '-1 day')
```

but I cannot believe that there is not a smarter manner

Comment: The SQL statement produced is `date("My_Table"."Entry date",  '+' + "My_Table"."Durée" || ' year', '-1 day'), '-1 day')` -> there are tow closing parentheses here but only one opening parenthesis.  Is the second '-1 day' part of another function or a typo?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: it was a typo Thank you. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given an answer on [github](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9515#discussioncomment-5380708). Credits go to **zzzeek**

> the behavior of the + operator switches on the kind of datatype that's in use. it only produces `||`, the string concatenation operator, if you have string datatypes in place.
>
> `FixedAsset.duration` appears to be an integer. you can't concatenate integers to strings, you'd have to use `SQL CAST to cast that integer as a string first:

```
print(SA.select(SA.func.date(FixedAsset.entry_date, "+" + SA.cast(FixedAsset.duration, SA.String) + " year", '-1 day')))
```